# move in treeview up or down via code in C#

Tags: c#, treeview

I am using Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise edition.   I have a treeview that I am using displaying a list of videos to watch.   How do I move one selection down (move to next video) via code or move up (previous video) via code.

Comment: WinForms WPF, ...? Do you want to Drag-and-Drop a selected node? You need to explain.

Comment: i am not trying to drag any thing.  I have a pre populated treeview.  in order the change the index is to click on an item.  how to i go the next item in the treeview via code without clicking on it.

Comment: Check [TreeNode.NextNode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.treenode.nextnode?view=netframework-4.8) and [TreeNode.PrevNode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.treenode.prevnode?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_TreeNode_PrevNode)

Comment: thank you.  That is what I needed to know. But I end up using NextVisibleNode and PreviousVisibleNode commands.  But thanks to leading to right direction.

Comment: when using the nextvisiblenode or nextnode is there a way to skip a node

Comment: Check if the `NextNode` or the `NextVisibleNode` of the clicked node is the one that you want to skip, then jump to it's next node,